# Fatal error with a theme

Tags: themes, errors

My question is about a theme named **[quality control](http://spencerfinnell.com/quality-control-theme/)** which was available at wordpress repository. The plugin developer is not available at this moment and I hope I get resolution for my problem here

These are the errors and many others are reporting the same error on the theme's official site

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class
>   WP_Error could not be converted to
>   string in
>   /public_html/wp-content/themes/quality-control/single.php
>   on line 55

and some times...

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class
>   WP_Error could not be converted to
>   string in
>   \wp-content\themes\quality-control\inc\templates\loop.php
>   on line 37

Could anybody help me with this? I am ready to give admin access to my site to replicate the error

**Update :**

The  WordPress version I am using is 3.1  and  I have tried both the 'Quality control' theme versions 1.5 and 2.0 versions .

http://ffav.in is the address of web-site and these are the URLs for some example posts with errors :

1) http:// ffav.in/ticket/test/

2) http:// ffav.in/category/uncategorized/

Thanks!

Comment: What's on line 55 of single.php and line 37 of loop.php? (save me/anyone having to download it just to check two lines of code).

Comment: t31os, I have mentioned the links and exact errors in the question. I have double checked. I could not solve it

Comment: I can give you the admin login details. But I am not certain if I can enter those details here.Please advice

Comment: Following [this blog](http://spencerfinnell.com/2011/02/01/on-quality-control/), i'd personally choose another theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is nothing problem with the theme. I had to create at-least one 'status'  before posting a ticket/post and change the Permalink settings.

Most of the bugs reported by other users about this theme might have occurred with modified  Permalink settings.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

First thing i ran across was [this conversation](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/quality-control-theme-ticket-priority?replies=13) about the same issue. I couldn't find it in the theme repo, but found it [accessible via svn](http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/quality-control/0.2/) @repo.

Now please answer some basic questions: Which version (wp & quality control) are you running? Could you share a link to your install? Which modifications have you made? Have you deactivated all plugins and tried to reproduce the error?

**EDIT**
I took a look at the repository (latest is version 1.2 - please take a look at the link from @Rarst to verify that this is the version you're using) and found the following theme functions called before your error messages:

- loop.php: `echo quality_ticket_status( $post->ID, 'slug' );` (2 times, line 29 & 35)
- singled.php: ... nothing

I'd suggest you tell us exactly (in your best english) every detail about the request that produces the error: which page you're on http://example.com/whatever-comes-here, what modifications you did, etc. Currently it's fishing in the dark.

Comment: Trac browser is little more friendly on the eyes than raw SVN version http://themes.trac.wordpress.org/browser/quality-control#0.2

Comment: I can give access to my wordPress powered site. Please let me know If Can send the login details to your mail or am I need enter it hear  Thanks!

Comment: See update of A. (Voting always appreciated)

Comment: I will update my question with detailed information.By the way the latest version is 2.0. Thanks!

Comment: Kaiser,Thanks for your help.I have updated the question with links to the pages which show error messages. Can you please login and check it by yourself if I give you the admin access to website?

Comment: @user3477: I just read t31os comment above about this thread: http://spencerfinnell.com/2011/02/01/on-quality-control/ and i can only aggree: go and spend the money, when the product is finished. It's always worth it (stable updates, security issues, etc.). So: thread closed.